# How to check if PowerShell is installed or not using C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to write a [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) method like

```
public bool PowershellExists()
{
    // Returns true if PowerShell exists on the machine, else false.
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/06/25/detection-logic-poweshell-installation.aspx + `Registry.GetValue`

Comment: Yeah got that, but I meant for a C# method.

Comment: Checking the registry is a C# method.  StackOverflow is not a tool for turning documentation into code.  If you don't understand registry or how to access it, you should research that.

Comment: So it's not about it not using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the MSDN blog post *[Detection logic for PowerShell installation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/06/25/detection-logic-poweshell-installation.aspx)*, I have written the method like:

```
public bool PowershellExists()
{
    string regval = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1", "Install", null).ToString();
    if (regval.Equals("1"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: can it also tell the Version ? or can we modify it to somehow get the Version Info ?

Comment: @N.K if you follow the link there is another key that let you know the version : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellEngine - in more recent version, you can look in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine